# Selenium RC getTitle method

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

it's been a long time :-)

I'm still with my learning of Selenium RC and I'm using the www.irishtimes.com as my tested application.

I have a very tiny test case that consists of these steps:

Selenium selenium;

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();

    selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost",
            SELENIUM_PORT,
            "*firefox",
            "http://www.irishtimes.com/");

    setUp("http://www.irishtimes.com/", "*firefox");
}
public void testTCNewspapers() throws Exception {
    selenium.start();
    selenium.open("http://www.irishtimes.com/");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    selenium.click("link=Life");

    //Doesn't work
    //verifyEquals("The Irish Times - Life", sel.getTitle());
```

}

When executing the verifyEquals I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.AssertionError: Expected "The Irish Times - Life" but saw "The Irish Times – Irish News, Business News, Sports News & Ireland Weather Online" instead
```

at com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestBase.fail(SeleneseTestBase.java:356)

I don't understand why this is happening since the title of the page is "The Irish Times - Life"

From the source html file:

```
<title>The Irish Times - Life</title>
```

Any help on resolving this? Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selenium doesn't wait for the new page to load after sending 'click'.

Try using 'clickAndWait' - that should cause Selenium to wait for a response from the server before continuing.

Comment: Thanks. Since there's not a clickAndWait method in the DefaultSelenium class I've used the waitPageToLoad("30000") method

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell Selenium to wait for the page to load.

See here: [Selenium IDE : Input too "early"](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.com/2010/10/selenium-ide-input-too-early.html)

Comment: Thanks, that was my solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I can clearly see the title from the source html file as,
The Irish Times – Irish News, Business News, Sports News & Ireland Weather Online I used chrome to view the source

Comment: Yes, you're right! Fore some reason it wasn't like that in my Firefox 2 days ago but now I can also see the complete title. However, my problem was different and it was related to the loading of the page